# expect script failing when called from a function in bash script

Tags: bash, function, time, expect

I have written a script that has several functions. There is several functions which are bash script - which make a call to an expect script. When I test the function in terminal it runs fine and completes - however when I test my entire script it hangs. If I remove the expect script's it will finish but it runs cumulative time and not what I would expect of a complete time of 6m30.400s which is the longest time'd function.

Is this the correct output to background the process and send stdout to the bit bucket - so that all processes will run concurrently `backup_ironport &> /dev/null` eg.

I ran the script with the first 6 functions and I expected it to take 2m48 seconds but it took 4m47 seconds - which seems to be running them separately and not concurrently.

```
time ./network-bak.sh 
real    4m47.033s
```

If I let it run all functions it hangs for over 15 minutes and I have to stop it. If I run functions separately in the shell to test it will complete. I ran bash -x and script and it just sits on the first expect script `backup_cisco_firewall` and goes no-where.

If I check the process in the system: `it sits there forever`

```
  ps aux |grep fw-bak-expect
  user  30925  0.0  0.0      0     0 pts/7    Z    10:18   0:00 [fw-bak-        expect.s] <defunct>
```

Here is a snip of the functions of the script and the run process: I tested each function in terminal with time function - and put the real time next to the function with the # tag to show how long it took to run.

```
backup_fortigate()
{ for fortigate in `cat "$h5"`; do scp $fortigate:sys_config     "$b3"/$fortigate-$date; done; } 

backup_cisco_firewall()
{ cd "$sc" ; for fw in `cat "$h2"`; do ./fw-bak-expect.sh $fw ; done; }

########################
#    Start of MAIN     #
# First Run the Backups#
########################
rotate &
rpid=$!
backup_ironport &> /dev/null # real 0m27.490s
backup_fortigate &> /dev/null # real    0m40.816s
backup_nexus &> /dev/null # real    0m35.346s
backup_switch-router &> /dev/null # real    2m48.649s
backup_rsa &> /dev/null # real  0m1.017s
backup_tlite &> /dev/null # real    0m29.589s
backup_cisco_firewall &> /dev/null # real   6m30.400s # no sys-context
backup_sw-no-pk &> /dev/null # real 4m6.729s
backup_esx &> /dev/null # real  1m24.330s
wait

##############################
# Now we confirm the backups #
##############################

confirm_backup > /dev/null
search_for_backups > /dev/null
vh1=$(wc -l < "$f1")
vh2=$(wc -l < "$f2")
backup_verify
# zero the verification files for the next run
cat /dev/null > "$f1"
cat /dev/null > "$f2"
cat /dev/null > "$mh"
kill -9 $rpid
echo "\b\b   "
```

Comment: seems to work fine once I removed > /dev/null and just have it function &

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`&>` syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Redirecting-Standard-Output-and-Standard-Error) is a short-hand to redirect both stdout and stderr at the same time, here to `/dev/null`. If you want to background the function call *and* drop the output, you need to include the actual backgrounding token:

```
...
backup_ironport &> /dev/null &
...
```